# Parent/Child Tables Query Pattern

Tags: sql, design-patterns, database-design

Suppose I have the following parent/child table relationship in my database:

`TABLE offer_master( offer_id int primary key, ..., scope varchar )
TABLE offer_detail( offer_detail_id int primary key, offer_id int foreign key, customer_id int, ... )`

where `offer_master.scope` can take on the value

- **INDIVIDUAL**: when the offer is to made to particular customers. In this case,
  whenever a row is inserted into `offer_master`, a corresponding row is 
  added to `offer_detail` for each customer to which the offer has been extended.

e.g.

`INSERT INTO offer_master( 1, ..., 'INDIVIDUAL' );
INSERT INTO offer_detail( offer_detail_id, offer_id, customer_id, ... )
    VALUES ( 1, 1, 100, ... )
INSERT INTO offer_detail( offer_detail_id, offer_id, customer_id, ... )
    VALUES ( 2, 1, 101, ... )`

- **GLOBAL**: when the offer is made to all customers. In this case,
  new offers can be added to the parent table as follows:

`INSERT INTO offer_master( 2, ..., 'GLOBAL' );
INSERT INTO offer_master( 3, ..., 'GLOBAL' );`

but a child row is added to `offer_detail` only 
when a customer indicates some interest in the offer. So 
it may be the case that, at some later point we will have

`INSERT INTO offer_detail( offer_detail_id, offer_id, customer_id, ... )
    VALUES ( 4, 3, 100, ... )`

Given this situation, suppose we would like to query the database 
to obtain all offers which have been extended to customer `100`; 
this includes 3 types of offers:

- offers which have been extended specifically to customer `100`.
- global offers which customer `100` showed no interest in.
- global offers which customer `100` did show interest in.

I see two approaches:

1. Using a Subquery:

   `SELECT * 
   FROM offer_master
   WHERE offer_id in (
       SELECT offer_id
       FROM offer_detail
       WHERE customer_id = 100 )
     OR scope = 'GLOBAL'`
2. Using a UNION

   `SELECT om.* 
   FROM offer_master om INNER JOIN
        offer_detail od
           ON om.offer_id = od.offer_id
   WHERE od.customer_id = 100
   UNION
   SELECT *
   FROM offer_master
   WHERE scope = 'GLOBAL'`

   *Note:* a `UNION ALL` cannot be used since a global offer
   which a customer has shown interest in would be duplicated.

My question is:

1. Does this query pattern have a name?
2. Which of the two query methods are preferable?
3. Should the database design be improved in some way?

Comment: Using one table to mean two different things is a bad idea.  Your offer_detail means "the offer is to made to particular customers" *and* "a customer indicates some interest in the offer". Fix this first.

Comment: I think the offer_detail table is currently representing offers made to particular customers *or* that a customer has indicated some interest in the offer.

Comment: Every row in a table should have the same predicate--the same kind of meaning. That means *one* kind of meaning, not two. If one row represents offers made and another row represents customer interest, you have a design problem. Fix this first.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Can you direct me to an elaboration on this design flaw?

Comment: Date's *Introduction to Database Systems*, 7th ed, section 3.4, entitled "What Relations Mean".

Comment: I changed the design to have `offer_detail` which contains individual offers and `offer_interest` for interest shown by customers. To collect all offers extended to a particular customer, I believe I still have to resort to one of the two queries I describe?

Comment: The only difference now would be that I could use a `UNION ALL` instead of a `UNION`.

Comment: If you don't record offers extended in a single table, you have to resort to a UNION or something that has a similar effect. Think hard about recording offers extended in a single table.

Comment: You're suggesting that `GLOBAL` and `INDIVIDUAL` offers be stored in separate tables?

Comment: I'm suggesting you think about (and test) storing offers extended in one table, and customer interest in another table.  That is, expand a global offer into an offer to each customer.

Comment: Aren't those two different things?
1. Different tables for offers and interest (which, as I've said, I've done).
2. Drop the 'global' aspect of the design and just add offers for each customer.

Comment: Two different but related things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a pattern name.

To me, the second query is clearer but I think either is OK.

offer_detail seems to be a dual purpose table which is a bit of a red flag to me.  You might have separate tables for the customers in an individual offer, and the customers who have expressed interest.